# Can JMP be run in batch mode on cluster?

Tags: sas-jmp

I need to do a large number of model fits using JMP, and would like to throw this onto our campus cluster (running either Windows or OS X).  This means that the analysis must be performed in batch mode, without opening a GUI, since the cluster nodes are headless.  I can use the JMP scripting capability to do the analyses on a single desktop system, but that will take too long and I've had no success at finding a way to invoke JMP without it popping up windows. Does anybody know if this can be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Many JMP commands allow an argument called "invisible" to avoid windows being created, if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't have **any** windows at all.  This means the actual JMP session itself must be windowless, not just the individual analyses.  I know how to launch JMP from a command-line, but as soon as I do it pops up a window.  That's what I need to disable.

Comment: You might try the JMP Community forum. I see a related but possibly out of date thread there: https://community.jmp.com/thread/9307.

Comment: That seems to confirm what my prior research had found.  An older version of JMP that worked on Linux could do it, but it didn't work for Windows or OS X and current versions of JMP don't support Linux.